# Bartenders friend left on too long

Tags: cleaning, kitchen-safety

Is it safe to use stainless steel pot after left bartenders friend on for 25-30 minutes?  Noticed it left a dark ring on bottom edge of the pot.  If I rinsed it thoroughly, is it still safe to use for cooking?

Answer (score 4):

According to the directions on my can, one is to rinse thoroughly within one minute of application.  From reading the mentioned ingredients on the can, and seeing the warning about potential "etching or dulling" of some surfaces, it appears that the acids and salts in the product are the most active ingredients.  I would think as long as you've rinsed your pot thoroughly, it is safe.  I think you do have some surface discoloration from leaving the product on so long. If you want to be absolutely certain though, there is a telephone number on the can that invites questions about the product: 1-800-433-5818.

Comment: There might be a risk of bacterial contamination if the etching opened up pores in the surface that they could grow in.

Comment: @nick012000 bacteria are generally neutralized at temps above 149°F (65°C).